# How to sort a matrix`s row based on another similar (not equivalent) matrix?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, row

I have two matrices with equal dimension in R. First columns are same. And they elements are such that they have same element but their position according to row and column are different. I am stating my problem with my code below:

```
A =matrix(c(1,  0,    0 ,   0 ,   0, 1,    0    ,0 ,   0  ,  2,     1  ,  0    ,0   , 0  ,  3,     1   , 0   , 0,    0 ,   4,     1   , 0  ,  0 ,   0,    5,     1,    0 ,   0  ,  2   , 3,     1,    0,    0   , 2  ,  4,     1,    0   , 0    ,2 ,   5,     1,    0  ,  0    ,3,    4,    1 ,   0  ,  0,    3  ,  5,    1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   5,    1 ,   0    ,2  ,  3,    4,    1 ,   0   , 2   , 3   , 5,    1 ,   0  ,  2    ,4  ,  5,    1 ,   0 ,   3   , 4 ,   5,    1  ,  2,    3    ,4,    5), nrow=16, byrow=TRUE)

B =matrix(c(1 ,   0    ,0,    0   , 0, 1,    0   , 0,    0 ,   5,    1,    0   , 0,    4 ,   0,     1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   4  ,  5,    1  ,  0 ,   3   , 0  ,  0,     1  ,  0   , 3,    0  ,  5,     1   , 0  ,  3 ,   4 ,   0,     1    ,0 ,   3  ,  4,    5,     1  ,  2,    0   , 0  ,  0,    1   , 2  ,  0,    0  ,  5,    1,    2 ,   0 ,   4 ,   0,    1 ,   2    ,0  ,  4    ,5,    1  ,  2   , 3   , 0   , 0,    1   , 2  ,  3    ,0  ,  5,    1   , 2 ,   3    ,4 ,   0,    1    ,2,    3    ,4,    5), nrow=16, byrow=TRUE)
```

This is the output:

```
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    2
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    3
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    4
 [5,]    1    0    0    0    5
 [6,]    1    0    0    2    3
 [7,]    1    0    0    2    4
 [8,]    1    0    0    2    5
 [9,]    1    0    0    3    4
[10,]    1    0    0    3    5
[11,]    1    0    0    4    5
[12,]    1    0    2    3    4
[13,]    1    0    2    3    5
[14,]    1    0    2    4    5
[15,]    1    0    3    4    5
[16,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

and

```
> B
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    5
 [3,]    1    0    0    4    0
 [4,]    1    0    0    4    5
 [5,]    1    0    3    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    3    0    5
 [7,]    1    0    3    4    0
 [8,]    1    0    3    4    5
 [9,]    1    2    0    0    0
[10,]    1    2    0    0    5
[11,]    1    2    0    4    0
[12,]    1    2    0    4    5
[13,]    1    2    3    0    0
[14,]    1    2    3    0    5
[15,]    1    2    3    4    0
[16,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

You can see the first columns are exactly similar, and last rows are too. The elements of the other rows are similar too but they are in different columns. Also corresponding rows do not contain similar elements.

Now, I want to sort the second matrix `B` according to `A`, that is the elements do not change their position based on columns, but just the row will be changed.

As for example, `A[3,]` and `B[5,]` contain same elements. I want `B[5,]` to be in the `B[3,]` position.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to solve your problem but one way to do so is by comparing every row of `A` with every row of `B`, to do that we use nested `apply`

within the lower apply loop we use some logic `y[all(sort(y) == sort(x))]`
which compares them after sorting them both

```
apply(A, 1, \(x) {
  apply(B, 1, \(y){
    y[all(sort(y) == sort(x))]
  })
}) |> 
  unlist() |> 
  matrix(ncol  = ncol(A), byrow = T)
```

If you have an older version of R ( < 4.1) without base piping, then you can run the code above like this:

```
matrix(
unlist(
  apply(A, 1, function(x) {
    apply(B, 1, function(y){
      y[all(sort(y) == sort(x))]
    })
  })
  ), 
ncol  = ncol(A), byrow = T)
```

This results in:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    2    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    3    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0    4    0
 [5,]    1    0    0    0    5
 [6,]    1    2    3    0    0
 [7,]    1    2    0    4    0
 [8,]    1    2    0    0    5
 [9,]    1    0    3    4    0
[10,]    1    0    3    0    5
[11,]    1    0    0    4    5
[12,]    1    2    3    4    0
[13,]    1    2    3    0    5
[14,]    1    2    0    4    5
[15,]    1    0    3    4    5
[16,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: the code doesnt work for me. It is giving me error

Comment: @LyT you probably have an older version of R than 4.1 installed (`|>` was introduced in that version). I added a different version which works for previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on this thread: [R::How would I match the rows of one matrix to the rows in another matrix, regardless of the column order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518369/rhow-would-i-match-the-rows-of-one-matrix-to-the-rows-in-another-matrix-regar)

```r
a <- t(apply(A,1,sort))
b <- t(apply(B,1,sort))

## match the sorted rows to find the position of each row in A
## then rearrange B based on that B[row_order, ]
B[match(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(a)), do.call(paste, as.data.frame(b))),] -> B_sorted

#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#>  [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
#>  [2,]    1    2    0    0    0
#>  [3,]    1    0    3    0    0
#>  [4,]    1    0    0    4    0
#>  [5,]    1    0    0    0    5
#>  [6,]    1    2    3    0    0
#>  [7,]    1    2    0    4    0
#>  [8,]    1    2    0    0    5
#>  [9,]    1    0    3    4    0
#> [10,]    1    0    3    0    5
#> [11,]    1    0    0    4    5
#> [12,]    1    2    3    4    0
#> [13,]    1    2    3    0    5
#> [14,]    1    2    0    4    5
#> [15,]    1    0    3    4    5
#> [16,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

```
## Spot Check to make sure the column orders are the same 
B_sorted[3,] == B[5,]
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
B_sorted[2,] == B[9,]
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

## check the rowSums between sorted B and A
all(rowSums(B_sorted) == rowSums(A))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

##### Data:

```
A =matrix(c(1,  0,    0 ,   0 ,   0, 1,    0    ,0 ,   0  ,  2,     1  ,  0    ,0   , 0  ,  3,     1   , 0   , 0,    0 ,   4,     1   , 0  ,  0 ,   0,    5,     1,    0 ,   0  ,  2   , 3,     1,    0,    0   , 2  ,  4,     1,    0   , 0    ,2 ,   5,     1,    0  ,  0    ,3,    4,    1 ,   0  ,  0,    3  ,  5,    1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   5,    1 ,   0    ,2  ,  3,    4,    1 ,   0   , 2   , 3   , 5,    1 ,   0  ,  2    ,4  ,  5,    1 ,   0 ,   3   , 4 ,   5,    1  ,  2,    3    ,4,    5), nrow=16, byrow=TRUE)

B =matrix(c(1 ,   0    ,0,    0   , 0, 1,    0   , 0,    0 ,   5,    1,    0   , 0,    4 ,   0,     1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   4  ,  5,    1  ,  0 ,   3   , 0  ,  0,     1  ,  0   , 3,    0  ,  5,     1   , 0  ,  3 ,   4 ,   0,     1    ,0 ,   3  ,  4,    5,     1  ,  2,    0   , 0  ,  0,    1   , 2  ,  0,    0  ,  5,    1,    2 ,   0 ,   4 ,   0,    1 ,   2    ,0  ,  4    ,5,    1  ,  2   , 3   , 0   , 0,    1   , 2  ,  3    ,0  ,  5,    1   , 2 ,   3    ,4 ,   0,    1    ,2,    3    ,4,    5), nrow=16, byrow=TRUE)
```